# combine two array and get new one

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i had an associative  array like this  : i need to merge two array and last hr rating i need to add hrrating1 =  , hr rating 2 =   like this

```
 array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'skill_name' => 'JDK (Java Development Kit)',
    'desc' => '',
    'req_rating' => '2',
    'user_rating' => '3',
    'hrRating' => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'skill_name' => 'Java Servlets',
    'desc' => '',
    'req_rating' => '4',
    'user_rating' => '3',
    'hrRating' => '3',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'skill_name' => 'JDK (Java Development Kit)',
    'desc' => '',
    'req_rating' => '2',
    'user_rating' => '3',
    'hrRating' => '2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'skill_name' => 'Java Servlets',
    'desc' => '',
    'req_rating' => '4',
    'user_rating' => '3',
    'hrRating' => '4',
  ),
)
```

Needed Output :

```
array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'skillName' => 'JDK',
            'comments' => '',
            'jobRating' => '2',
            'userRating' => '3',
            'skillGap' => '-1',
            'hrRating1' => '7',
            'hrRating2' => '2',

          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'skillName' => 'Java Servlets',
            'comments' =>'',
            'jobRating' =>'4',
            'userRating' =>'3',
            'skillGap' => '1',
            'hrRating1' => '2',
            'hrRating2' => '3',

          ),
        )
```

i need to combine both array with last column hrRating should different like hrRating1 & hrrating@ like this any help regarding????

Comment: Do you want to combine only hrRating field of whole array?

Comment: combine all the thing and add hrRating also - finally i need to get one array only with hrrating combination also

Comment: try PHP function array_merge

Comment: provide sample output for better understanding of what you are looking for

Comment: Can't you make `hrRating` as an array?? should be easy and better instead of having multiple `hrRating` keys

Comment: I agree with @Yash, in fact maybe you should turn *all* your properties into arrays? Their average value can be calculated easily and they better represent the underlying data structure.

Comment: Take a look https://www.dyn-web.com/php/arrays/combine.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** (single array input)
I do not know if I can use `skill_name` as a array key (probably not), hence `$tmp_skill`, `$tmp_index`.

```
function process_collection($data) {

    $tmp_skill = [];
    $tmp_index = [];
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $k => $item) {
        $skill = $item['skill_name'];
        echo $skill.'<br>';
        $idx = array_search($skill, $tmp_skill);
        if ($idx === false) {
            //$result[$idx]['_ratings'] = $item['hrRating'];
            //continue;
            $idx = count($tmp_skill);
            $tmp_index[] = $idx;
            $tmp_skill[] = $skill;
            $result[$idx] = $item;
            $result[$idx]['_ratings'] = [];
        }
        $result[$idx]['_ratings'][] = $item['hrRating'];
    }  

    // conversion array of ratings to individual values 'hrRating1', 'hrRating2', ...
    foreach($result as &$item) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $item['_ratings'] as $rate)
            $item['hrRating' . (++$i)] = $rate;
        unset($item['_ratings']);
        unset($item['hrRating']);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: don't consider as two arrays.  it is a collection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_merge()` merge function to combine arrays as following:

```
$comined_array=array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Now the `$combined_array` will be containing the value of both `$array1` and `$array2`.

Comment: all the two arrays are in the collection so how to separate the array ???? and combine check  $get_skills --- looping two times - two array will come

Comment: the above array that you have posted, I guess you just need to push the extra hrrating key in your array, so rather than merging the array what you can do is just to push the extra rating key in your already existing array using the PHP's array_push() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_2    = max($arra_1,$arra)    ;
```

print_r($array_2);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [skillName] => JDK [comments] => [jobRating] => 2 [userRating] => 3 [skillGap] => -1 [hrRating] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [skillName] => Java Servlets [comments] => [jobRating] => 4 [userRating] => 3 [skillGap] => 1 [hrRating] => 3 ) )
```

Comment: change the $arra_1 & $arra as per your array names.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). The function [array combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is an array of keys and then values whereas array merge append arrays onto the first.

As mentioned in the other answers, change the array variables to match your own.

```
$array_1 = ['a'];
$array_2 = ['b'];

$new_array = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);

print_r($new_array);
// ['a', 'b']
```

Find more array functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can try any from these alternatives:-
***Assuming that both the array's has same elements and keys and named it as `$arr1` and `$arr2`***
Alternative 1 :- Make an array of all `hrRating` and asign it to main array

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $data) {
    $arr1[$key]['hrRating'] = array($data['hrRating'], $arr2[$key]['hrRating']);
}
print_r($arr1);
```

Output :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [skillName] => JDK
            [comments] => 
            [jobRating] => 2
            [userRating] => 3
            [skillGap] => -1
            [hrRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 7
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [skillName] => Java Servlets
            [comments] => 
            [jobRating] => 4
            [userRating] => 3
            [skillGap] => 1
            [hrRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Alternative 2 :- Assign every `hrRating` values from different array with new sequence key

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $data) {
    unset($arr1[$key]['hrRating']);
    $arr1[$key]['hrRating1'] = $data['hrRating'];
    $arr1[$key]['hrRating2'] = $arr2[$key]['hrRating'];
}
print_r($arr1);
```

Output :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [skillName] => JDK
            [comments] => 
            [jobRating] => 2
            [userRating] => 3
            [skillGap] => -1
            [hrRating1] => 2
            [hrRating2] => 7
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [skillName] => Java Servlets
            [comments] => 
            [jobRating] => 4
            [userRating] => 3
            [skillGap] => 1
            [hrRating1] => 3
            [hrRating2] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: dont take it is two array is  a collection  i just printed the collection array

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the variety: Here is another way of re-arranging your array. I took the liberty of combining all arrays into a single master array `$in`. By doing a sequence of `foreach` calls will get your result fairly quickly.

I also added the feature that I named the individual rating arrays after their `skill_name`. If you don't like that, just comment out the line below:

```
// $j=$aa['skillName'];unset($aa['skillName']);
```

Here is the input data I used for testing:

```
$in=array(
  array (
      array (
    'skillName' => 'JDK',
    'comments' => '',
    'jobRating' => '2',
    'userRating' => '3',
    'skillGap' => '-1',
    'hrRating' => '2',
   ), array (
    'skillName' => 'Java Servlets',
    'comments' =>'',
    'jobRating' =>'4',
    'userRating' =>'3',
    'skillGap' => '1',
    'hrRating' => '3',
   ),
  ), 
  array (
      array (
    'skillName' => 'JDK',
    'comments' => '',
    'jobRating' => '2',
    'userRating' => '3',
    'skillGap' => '-1',
    'hrRating' => '7',
   ), array (
    'skillName' => 'Java Servlets',
    'comments' =>'',
    'jobRating' =>'4',
    'userRating' =>'3',
    'skillGap' => '1',
    'hrRating' => '2',
   )
  ), 
  array (
      array (
    'skillName' => 'JDK',
    'comments' => 'not bad',
    'jobRating' => '3',
    'userRating' => '3',
    'skillGap' => '-1',
    'hrRating' => '4',
  ),  array (
    'skillName' => 'Java Servlets',
    'comments' =>'',
    'jobRating' =>'8',
    'userRating' =>'3',
    'skillGap' => '1',
    'hrRating' => '1',
  ),
));
```

And this is the complete code for re-arranging:

```
foreach ($in as $i => $na) foreach($na as $j => $aa) {
  $j=$aa['skillName'];unset($aa['skillName']);
  foreach ($aa as $k => $v) $ret[$j][$k][]=$v;
}

print_r($ret);
```

And this is what I get as output:

```
Array
(
    [JDK] => Array
        (
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => not bad
                )

            [jobRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [userRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [skillGap] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -1
                    [1] => -1
                    [2] => -1
                )

            [hrRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 4
                )

        )

    [Java Servlets] => Array
        (
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                )

            [jobRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 8
                )

            [userRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [skillGap] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [hrRating] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

See the demo here: http://rextester.com/WEUQ12234

Answer (score -1):

you can combine arrays in two ways:

```
$third_array = combine_array($array1,$array2);
```

and the other way is:

```
$array = $array1 + $array2;
```

change the $array1 & $array2 as per your array names.